# Testing App on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have unlocked my Nokia Lumia phone for development.
1. I would like to know if I can test my app on my phone for any longer or is it restricted to some time period like 30 days. (I have not paid $19,as I am not planning on publishing the app as of now)
2. Also is there any restriction on the number of apps that I can test on the same phone with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn614128.aspx)

> A Microsoft account
>
> How do I sign up for a Microsoft account?
>
> •Optionally, a valid and current developer account on Windows Phone Dev Center
>
> Join
>
> If you have a developer account, you can register three devices to use for app development, and you can publish apps in the Windows Phone Store.
>
> If you don’t have a developer account, you can only register one device to use for app development. Before you can publish apps in the Windows Phone Store, you have to register.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have developer account you can deploy app for limited time and you can deploy max 3 apps at once. If you have developer account then time period increases and you can deploy 10 apps at once.